# Selenium > Replace the last part of an URL

Tags: java, string, selenium

I have a URL with some dynamic parts

```
https://{env}-my-website.{domain}/UnDefault.aspx
```

And every time I want to go to another module I have to replace this part

```
UnDefault.aspx
```

with the module to which I want to navigate **e.g.**

```
Modules/Repairs/SNH.aspx
```

Is there an easy way to do that with Selenium or Regex?

this is what i tried :

```
String currentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
String[] results = StringUtils.substringsBetween(currentUrl, "https", "?:cn|com");
String SNH= results[0]+"Modules/Repairs/SNH.aspx";
driver.navigate().to(SNH);
```

Comment: Do you want to replace the part after the last slash? If not, please give some examples of input url and new value and desired output.

Comment: It is possible to use String#format method. You can use a string with a format (a.k.a. template) containing the static parts, then "formatting" it with the dynamic parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the path part of the url (everything after the server):

```
String url = url.replaceAll("^(.*?//[^/]+/).*", "$1Modules/Repairs/SNH.aspx");
```